# Text Not changing color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the color of the text and it is not working.

This is what I have:

```
function LinesForKeyword($container, word) {
        var word = word.trim();
        // wrap each word in a span and add it to a tmp
        var tmp = '';
        //$.each(word, function (i, word) {
        for (var i = 0; i < reservedKeyWords.length; i++) {
            if (word == reservedKeyWords[i]) {

                word=word.replace(word, '[<font color="blue">'+word+'</font>]'); 

            }

        }
```

When I step through the code in debug mode, it says that the font color is changed, by that I mean this is when i hover over `word` in debug mode this is what it displays:

`"[<font color="blue">string</font>]"`

Then once it's done it never actually updates the color, it just stays black :(

Comment: You don't appear to be putting the data in an HTML document (and the font element was superseded by CSS over a decade ago)

Comment: I'm having a nightmare where it's 1998 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the font color with JavaScript, simply use the following prior to your `.replace()` method call:

```
word.style.color = "blue";
```

And for the sake of all our sanity, please don't use the `<font>` tag as it's extinction is as old as the dinosaurs.

Here's an example for what I believe it is you're looking for. Please be sure to change code where needed:

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");

    var keywords = [ "is", "test" ];

    for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < spans.length; j++) {
            if (spans[j].innerHTML === keywords[i]) {
                spans[i].style.color = "blue";
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">This <span class="myClass">is</span> a <span class="myClass">test</span></div>
```

Here's a jfiddle for your convenience too:

http://jsfiddle.net/pbhwLngo/

**Edit #2:**

Here's an example with minor jQuery. It grabs all `<span>` elements inside a specific element and does the same thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/pbhwLngo/4/

Comment: This won't work either (as is). The word needs to be wrapped in an element before it can be styled.

Comment: @Juhana Good point. My answer quite possibly should be removed as we don't have an idea of OP's HTML structure. But you are absolutely right that it does need to be wrapped in an element.

Comment: I have it wrapped in a `span` element, but I dont know how to make the word turn blue.

Comment: @bbesase Is each word you wish to change the color to blue wrapped in a `span` element?

Comment: @DrewKennedy yes they are

Comment: @bbesase Please check the edits in my answer and let me (us) know if that's what you're aiming for.

Comment: Your way works if I have a pre-defined span class, but what if I'm taking each individual word that is typed in a textbox and wrapping each individual word inside a span tag?

Comment: @bbesase I'm assuming you're okay with using jQuery since it is tagged in your question and is used a little in your example above. Please check the new Fiddle in the answer I have provided for you.